# How to customise WYSIWYG editor in admin form - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, tinymce

I need to add `directionality : 'rtl'` to WYSIWYG editor used in all admin forms (Product create/edit, category form).

[image]

How can I configure TinyMCE editor since the instruction [provided here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/wysiwyg/configure-tinymce-editor.html) is not clear enough?

When looked into TinyMCE documentation, it has option like,

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  directionality : 'ltr'
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you create the form by UI component or block?

Comment: @MichaelHa I need this to be in effect in all core pages like product create/edit page and category page in admin.

Comment: https://swiftotter.com/technical/adding-styles-to-magento-2-s-wysiwyg-editor#/ maybe it will help you.